# Lara talks at hyperspeed?

Tags: pc, backwards-compatibility, tomb-raider-the-angel-of-darkness

I found an old old copy of *Tomb Raider: The Angel of Darkness*. I got it installed and at first it ran super-fast. So I googled and found the advice to turn on Wait For V-Sync. Now the menu and game speed runs normally. But the voices don't. They speed by so fast that if I didn't have subtitles on, I wouldn't know what's being said.

How can I fix it?

My laptop that I'm playing on has Windows XP, I haven't tried my Windows 7 computer at home but I'm travelling and won't be able to for a while.

Comment: Hello, ERJ! "Tomb Raider: Angel of Darkness" cannot be used as a tag alone because it is too long. (tags are limited to 25 characters). In the meantime, I have changed it to just be, "The Angel of Darkness".

Comment: And here I thought everyone who plays tomb raider games weren't doing it for the dialog ;)

Comment: I think I might actually play a Tomb Raider game, for the sheer hilarity, if the voices sound like Alvin and the Chipmunks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Tomb Raider Chronicles](http://www.tombraiderchronicles.com/tng/faq.html)

> Lara sounds like a chipmunk. Talks very fast.
>
> Update the sound card driver. Confirmed problem on the Realtek Sound
>   chip. If this still doesn't work go to your Windows Control Panel
>   (->Start ->Settings ->Control Panel. Click Sound and Multimedia. Once
>   you are in Sound and Multimedia Properties click the Audio tab. In the
>   box 'Sound Playback' click Advanced, choose the Performance-tab and
>   set the Hardware acceleration from Full acceleration to Basic
>   acceleration or No Acceleration.

This sort of thing happens a lot with old games in general where the clock speed of component X didn't scale properly.